# The following RangeError was thrown building GetX<MzfUsersController>(controller: Instance of 'MzfUsersController', tag: null,

Tags: flutter, dart

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building GetX(controller: Instance of
'MzfUsersController', tag: null, has builder, dirty, state:
GetXState#a8779(controller: Instance of 'MzfUsersController')):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1

```
                  The relevant error-causing widget was:
                    GetX<MzfUsersController>
                    GetX:file:///D:/flutter_egitim/GedikKaynak-App-versiyon-3/lib/views/portal/home/menu_widget.dart:131:26
```

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
                      #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
                      #1      MenuWidget.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:gedik_holding/views/portal/home/menu_widget.dart:138:48)
                      #2      GetXState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_getx_widget.dart:131:29)
                      #3      RxInterface.notifyChildren (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_interface.dart:26:27)
                      #4      GetXState.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_getx_widget.dart:129:53)
                      #5      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
                      #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
                      #7      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
                      #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
                      #9      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
                      #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
                      #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
```

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  child: GetX<MzfUsersController>( //Error line
                    init: MzfUsersController(),
                    builder: (data) {
                      List bayiiList = data.userList;
                      List bayiiCodeList = data.userCodes;
                      return FormBuilderDropdown(
                        clearIcon: Container(),
                        initialValue: bayiiList[bayiiCodeList.indexWhere((bayi) => bayi.startsWith(GetStorage().read("bayiiUserCode") ?? "1"))],
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          Get.put(BayiiController()).changeBayii(bayiiCodeList[bayiiList.indexWhere((bayi) => bayi.startsWith(value))]);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                        name: 'bayii',
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Bayii',
                        ),
                        allowClear: true,
                        hint: Text('Bayii Seç'),
                        validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([FormBuilderValidators.required(Get.context)]),
                        items: bayiiList
                            .map((bayii) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: bayii,
                                  child: Text(
                                    '$bayii',
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                  ),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```